# How can I convert the drawn rectangle to a Cube (3d cube)?

Tags: unity, c#

The main idea is just to replace the drawn rectangle with a cube and the cube will have the same size and same position of the drawn rectangle relative to the camera and to the mouse position so the cube will be in front of me the player and not some where far in space.

In the Update:

```
void Update()
    {
        // If we press the left mouse button, save mouse location and begin selection
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isSelecting = true;
            mousePosition1 = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        // If we let go of the left mouse button, end selection
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isSelecting = false;
            GenerateBoxFromRectangle(rect, Input.mousePosition);
        }

        currentMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

OnGUI

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isSelecting)
        {
            // Create a rect from both mouse positions
            rect = DrawRectangle.GetScreenRect(mousePosition1, Input.mousePosition);
            DrawRectangle.Utils.DrawScreenRect(rect, new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.95f, 0.25f));
            DrawRectangle.Utils.DrawScreenRectBorder(rect, 2, new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.95f));
        }
    }
```

The DrawRectangle script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawRectangle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Rect GetScreenRect(Vector3 screenPosition1, Vector3 screenPosition2)
    {
        // Move origin from bottom left to top left
        screenPosition1.y = Screen.height - screenPosition1.y;
        screenPosition2.y = Screen.height - screenPosition2.y;
        // Calculate corners
        var topLeft = Vector3.Min(screenPosition1, screenPosition2);
        var bottomRight = Vector3.Max(screenPosition1, screenPosition2);
        // Create Rect
        return Rect.MinMaxRect(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
    }

    public static class Utils
    {
        static Texture2D _whiteTexture;
        public static Texture2D WhiteTexture
        {
            get
            {
                if (_whiteTexture == null)
                {
                    _whiteTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
                    _whiteTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.white);
                    _whiteTexture.Apply();
                }

                return _whiteTexture;
            }
        }

        public static void DrawScreenRect(Rect rect, Color color)
        {
            GUI.color = color;
            GUI.DrawTexture(rect, WhiteTexture);
            GUI.color = Color.white;
        }

        public static void DrawScreenRectBorder(Rect rect, float thickness, Color color)
        {
            // Top
            Utils.DrawScreenRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMin, rect.width, thickness), color);
            // Left
            Utils.DrawScreenRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMin, thickness, rect.height), color);
            // Right
            Utils.DrawScreenRect(new Rect(rect.xMax - thickness, rect.yMin, thickness, rect.height), color);
            // Bottom
            Utils.DrawScreenRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMax - thickness, rect.width, thickness), color);
        }
    }
}
```

Back to the main script the GenerateBoxFromRectangle method:

```
private void GenerateBoxFromRectangle(Rect rectangle, Vector3 mousePosition)
    {
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 0);
        cube.transform.localPosition = mousePosition;
    }
```

But the code in the method GenerateBoxFromRectangle is not making the cube I wanted.

What I want to do is once I left the mouse left button to create from the rectangle size a 3d cube on the size of the rectangle and the cube position should be from the current(when leaving the mouse left mouse button) input.mouseposition to the side of the drawn rectangle depending if I dragged the mouse when drawing the rectangle to the right or to the left.

I mean the drawn area of the rectangle should be the position of the cube.
The cube should be replacing the rectangle.

This is a screenshot example of drawn rectangle:

[image: Drawn Rectangle]

Now I tried this in the GenerateBoxFromRectangle method:

```
private void GenerateBoxFromRectangle(Rect rectangle, Vector3 mousePosition)
    {
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = mRay.origin + (mRay.direction * 2.0f);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(rectangle.width, rectangle.height, 1);
    }
```

The size scale is not the same as the rectangle not even close.

The position I'm not sure yet if it's in the same position of the mouse cursor but in the end the cube should be in the rectangle position to replace the rectangle. I mean to be in the same place where the rectangle is.

Update:

I tried this now:

```
private void GenerateBoxFromRectangle(Rect rectangle, Vector3 mousePosition)
    {
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = mRay.origin + (mRay.direction * 2.0f);
        Vector3 scale = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(rectangle.width,rectangle.height,0));
        cube.transform.localScale = scale;
    }
```

But it's creating a very big cube, I tried also:

```
Vector3 scale = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(rectangle.x,rectangle.y,0));
```

But the cube is too large.

Comment: The scale isn't the same because the rectangle is drawn in screen space (range 0-1 on both axis) and the cube is in world space. Also, stop using `OnGUI()` and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) instead.